# First order system of linear pds stability analysis

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve system of first order linear pde's;

$u_t = -aw_y$ and $w_t = au_y$, where $u_t,w_t$; $u_y,w_y$ are differentials in time and space. $a$ is a constant. Is there any standard way to solve this eqs analytically and also how can I do the stability analysis?

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate the first equation with respect to $t$ and the second with respect to $y$ (and vice versa) to find that $u$ and $w$ satisfy the same equation:

\begin{align*}
 u_{tt} + a^2 u_{yy} & = 0 \\
 w_{tt} + a^2 w_{yy} & = 0 
\end{align*}

Use now the method of characteristics to solve for one of them (you'll find imaginary characteristics since the PDEs are elliptic, provided $a$ is real) and substitute the other from one of the 1st order original PDEs.

Can you take it from here?

*Hint*: the algebra is slightly easier if you consider $x = y/a$.